# MySQL stored prod insert from IN data and other table

Tags: mysql

I have an INSERT statement below, taking from 3 inputs that will be passed from a php post request. The statement below returns an error

```
INSERT INTO orderitems (orderId, productId, quantity, productName, price) (korderid, kproductid,kquantity, SELECT p.productName, p.price from products p WHERE p.id=kproductid)
```

The error being:

````
 The following query has failed: "CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateOrderItem`(IN `korderid` INT(8), IN `kproductid` INT(8), IN `kquantity` INT(8)) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER INSERT INTO orderitems (orderId, productId, quantity, productName, price) (korderid, kproductid,kquantity, SELECT p.productName, p.price from products p WHERE p.id=kproductid)" 

 MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'korderid, kproductid,kquantity, SELECT p.productName, p.price from products p...' at line 1 ```
````

Comment: You forgot to define you are inserting values `INSERT INTO tablename (fields) VALUES (values)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention how you're doing with the post data. But here is how it could be done:

```
INSERT INTO orderitems (orderId, productId, quantity, productName, price)
SELECT :orderid, p.id, :quantity, p.productName, p.price
FROM products p
WHERE p.id = :productid
```

The `:xyz` indicates parameters for the query.

Comment: I think that is OP want

Comment: I have updated my query and replaced the {:xyz} to my post data and it works wonderfully